# can hue be installed on hadoop without any distributions like ambari,cloudera or hortonworks on CENTOS?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hue

I am new to big-data stack. Our current cluster is having hive, hadoop, spark and other services without the help of cloudera, ambari or any other distributions.

I am trying to install hue, so that it can help is in viewing tables and other functionalities but couldn't found proper steps to do on CENTOS.

hive is currently being accessed from command line interface.

Answer (score 0):

This page has instructions on how to build and install from sources: [How to build Hue on Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty](http://gethue.com/how-to-build-hue-on-ubuntu-14-04-trusty/). Adapt accordingly for CentOS. Once you succesfully build it and startup the server, it should connect automatically to your cluster provided you start the server on a node that is already a cluster node or has the Hadoop environment configured to point to your cluster. If not, follow [Integrate Hue with your Hadoop cluster](http://gethue.com/yahoo-hadoop-meetup-integrate-hue-with-your-hadoop-cluster/).